# Taylor expansion and finding the velocity

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Assuming the particle travels only a short distance compared to $r_0$, Taylor expand the bracket in the following equation to include $O(t)$ and $O(t^2)$ terms.
>   What is $v_0$ in this case?
>   $$r = (r_0 ^{3/2} + 3t\sqrt{GM/2})^{2/3}$$

ok so far I have tried to taylor expand the equation, and got some [nasty hell of an answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=f9476968629e1163bd4a3ba839d60925&title=Taylor%20Series&theme=blue&i0=(z%5E(2%2F3)%2B3t(GM%2F2)%5E(1%2F2))%5E(2%2F3)&i1=z&i2=0&i3=10&podSelect=&showAssumptions=1&showWarnings=1) with no $O(t)$ terms or $O(t^2)$ terms, from that equation how should I work on to get $v_0$? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The units don't seem to match -- shouldn't the equation be $r = (r_0^{\color{red}{3/2}} + 3t\sqrt{GM/2})^{2/3}$?

Comment: @kobe Nice catch.  IMO, units with fractional exponents sounds horrifying though.

Comment: @Michael.K It helps to [invent parameters to simplify things](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+(1%2Ba*t)%5E(2%2F3)).  Edit: I just looked at your link -- you're supposed to be expanding this in $t$, not $r_0$.

Comment: apologies its supposed to be r^(3/2) just edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the $r_0^{2/3}$ is supposed to be $r_0^{3/2}$ instead, we have

$$r = r_0 + \frac{2}{3}(r_0^{3/2})^{2/3 - 1}\left(3t\sqrt{GM/2}\right) + \frac{(2/3)(2/3-1)}{2}(r_0^{3/2})^{2/3-2}(3t\sqrt{GM/2})^2 + \cdots $$

Simplifying, we find that the coefficient of $t$ is $\sqrt{2GM/r_0}$, so $$v_0 = \sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r_0}}$$